# Как реализовать смахивание элементов в pwa?

Tags: javascript, css, spa, pwa

Есть у нас квадратный div внизу страницы, я хочу чтоб пользователь могут потянуть его вниз и закрыть. Есть мысль накинуть ресайз и при определенном значении проигрывать анимацию закрытия вниз и скрывать блок. Но как еще можно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.